# Azure python sdk not working

Tags: python, azure, typeerror, azure-resource-manager

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

def run_example():
    """Resource Group management example."""
    #
    # Create all clients with an Application (service principal) token provider
    #
    subscription_id = os.environ['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID']

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
        secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
    )
    compute_client=ComputeManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)

    ###########
    # Prepare #
    ###########

    # List VM in resource group
    print('\nList VMs in resource group')
    for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list():
        print("\tVM: {}".format(vm.name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_example()
```

We installed azure python sdk on ubuntu server and did all the necessary steps. but still this sample code giving following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_example()
  File "app.py", line 18, in run_example
    compute_client=ComputeManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

We used [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/blob/master/example.py) to create this example.

Comment: whats your package and python versions?

Comment: Trying `pip install azure-mgmt-compute==0.30.0rc5`.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT : thanks, working now.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you mention, please look at the "[requirements.txt](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/blob/master/requirements.txt)" file to have the necessary version.

My guess is you are using "pip install azure" that will unfortunately install currently a too old package for this tutorial. See Installation note on ReadTheDocs or the Github frontpage:

- http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python#installation

TL;DR;, please use "pip install --pre azure" or directly "pip install azure-mgmt-compute"

Comment: thank you :)..working good , I updated following python modules from requirements.txt as azure-mgmt-compute==0.30.0rc5 & haikunator.